# How to reload data in UIViewController inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 child ViewContollers in a NavigationController. There is a UISwitch in the 2nd one that changes how I query a backend API in the 1st one.

This is my code in the 2nd one:

```
@IBAction func ordersTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "showPastOrders")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "showPastOrders")
        }
    }
```

This is my code in the 1st one:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let orderList = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showPastOrders")
        loadOrderData(past: orderList)
}
```

The problem is, whenever I swap back and forth between the ViewControllers, the Userdefaults boolean value I set, is not read. I tried overriding the viewDidAppear to obtain the value but that did not help either.

So how would I obtain the boolean value each time when I jump back and forth between the VCs?

Comment: I would not expect `viewDidLoad` to work if you are going between existing controllers that already have their views in memory.  `viewDidAppear` is more of a mystery.  I suggest trying that again and using the debugger to check that it's being called and what `UserDefaults` is giving you.

Comment: viewDidAppear is being called and I am getting the right value from UserDefaults. That's why this is puzzling at the moment.

Comment: Now I'm confused.  If you use `viewDidAppear` and get the right value there, what's the problem?

Comment: I realized what the problem was. I need to reload the table in this function as well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can fix it by setting up a didSet call on the Bool.

```
var showPastOrders: Bool {
   didSet {
       orderList = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showPastOrders")
       // view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
}
```

Now if setting the showPastOrders is not set correctly I would recommend delegation or passing the data with the segue, depending on how you set up your project.

Hope it helps.